# Web app for online auction site?

Tags: web-apps, ecommerce

Looked at a ton of auction software from Google and checked out everything in github. There's some potential choices there but want to investigate further before making a final decision. The auction software I'm looking for will:

1. Run auctions like eBay with exception the house creates all auctions
   and users only bid (users don't put items up for auction)
2. Hosted on company servers (no cloud-license / white label etc)
3. Customizable as the eBay-style is not the only auction method we
   will use
4. Can be paid software and does not have to be open-source although
   open-source will be fine (I couldn't find anything that was stable
   on github but haven't looked everywhere yet)
5. Prefer non-CMS plugin/module (The site will be 100% auction and so a
   dedicated software to auctions would be nice)
6. Must be stable enough to run out-of-the-box even without all the
   features we will need to develop (ie an eBay clone ready to spin up
   and test and build further develop from)

Comment: Wouldn’t it still be a CMS, albeit a specialized one?

Comment: I guess it is on a technical level that anything else is dealing with content. I mainly didn't include the cms tag because I wanted to avoid mostly, "Check out this Drupal module" answers.